# How can I connect tables LogisticsElectronicAddress and HcmWorker?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I need the **PersonnelNumber** from **HcmWorker** table, but the value I am receiving is an **E-mail address** from **LogisticsElectronicAddress** is there a possible connection/sql statement where I can find the PersonnelNumber by using the E-mail address? They are in the same form named **HcmWorker**

Answer (score 3):

I hope to understood the question.

**LogisticsElectronicAddress** is related to **LogisticsLocation** by RedcId, and **LogisticsLocation** to **DirPartyTable** by table **DirPartyLocation** by RecId too.

So, Worker, insered in **HcmWorker** are related to **DirPartyTable** by Table **DirPerson** with RecId.

So, If you have the LogisticsElectronicAddress you can have a backwards approach.

Look like this code:

```
select LogisticsElectronicAddress
  join LogisticsLocation
  join DirPartyLocation
  join DirPartyTable
  join HcmWorker
  join DirPerson // extended DirPartyTable
 where LogisticsLocation.RecId == LogisticsElectronicAddress.Location
    && DirPartyLocation.Location == LogisticsLocation.RecId
    && DirPartyTable.RecId == DirPartyLocation.Party
    && DirPerson.RecId == DirPartyTable.RecId
    && HcmWorker.Person == DirPerson.RecId;
```

Try to see all related Table (relation, fields, values). 
Be careful you can get alias/ not unique values, add more condition (see the Key-Index).

Enjoy!